# problems display single quote in IE

Tags: xml, xslt, quote, apostrophe

I am using XSLT and XML to generate a web page and having a problem with the single quote working in IE.

I  have a paragraph tag with text that is suppose to say "`Student's` courses are:". Also, I have a course title called MORAL PROBLEMS:CONTEMP'RY from the XML.

However when viewing the HTML in IE, it appears as `Student&apos;s courses are` and for the title, it shows up as `PROBLEMS:CONTEMP&apos;RY`. In Firefox and chrome, it shows up properly as `Student's courses are:` and `MORAL PROBLEMS:CONTEMP'RY`.

In my XSLT, I have tried many things such as putting in "`Student&#39;`", but it still does not show the `'` in IE.

Here is the XML

```
<courses_xml>
  <taken_courses>
    <course_subj>PHIL</course_subj>
    <course_no>235</course_no>
    <title>MORAL PROBLEMS:CONTEMP&apos;RY</title>
    <term_code>200805</term_code>
    <grade>B</grade>
  </taken_course>
  <taken_courses>
    <course_subj>MATH</course_subj>
    <course_no>200</course_no>
    <title>ADVANCED CALCULUS</title>
    <term_code>200805</term_code>
    <grade>A</grade>
  </taken_course>
<courses_xml>
```

Here is the XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
version="1.0">

<xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
        <body>
        <p>Student's courses are:</p>  
        <table>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="courses_xml"/>
        </table>   
        </body>
    </html>  
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="/courses_xml/taken_courses">
    <tr>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="course_subj"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="course_no"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="title"/></td> 
        <td><xsl:value-of select="grade"/></td>
    </tr>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Are you really missing the ";" in the entity reference or is that just for formatting of your question? (It should be `&apos;`.)

Comment: It should be &apos; but i didn't know to how to format it so it would show that.

Comment: And is there a reason you haven't shown us the relevant XSLT/XML yet? Are we supposed to fix it for you without having seen it?